# Como obtener length de una respuesta de AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen dia tengo una vista donde recibo datos de parte de Ajax al momento de querer acceder al length me tira error probe con de dos maneras, la segunda manera me arroja 15 y ese no es el resultado correcto. De antemano gracias.

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/test.json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.length) //Metodo 1 (Resultado = undefined)
        console.log(data.toString().length) //Metodo 2 (Resultado = siempre 15)
    }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El resultado de la consulta es un objeto que contiene una clave llamada `data`, lo correcto sería: `success: function(result) { ... }`, y dentro del cuerpo de la función obtienes la data así: `console.log(result.data.length);`. Saludos

Comment: Amigo, me funciono correctamente... Te lo agradezco bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que nombraste el parámetro de la función y el objeto con el mismo nombre, en este caso:

> data.data.length

deberá funcionar.

Aunque para hacer el código más legible te recomiendo:

```js
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/test.json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.length); // si falla response.data intenta con la otra manera.
        console.log(response['data'].length);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo obtuve lo que queria... perdona por tu tiempo, pero para poder acceder a una "columna" de ese objeto podria ser response.data."Producto" ? Coloque una img, y a ese quisiera acceder para todos los registros no solo a una linea

Comment: permíteme ver el objeto en consola, sin verlo lo primero que intentaría es response.data[0]['Producto']; o bien response.data[0].Producto; para ver el de la primera iteración.

Comment: Ya puse la imagen, quisiera acceder a ese pero para los 18... he visto algunos ejemplos pero no me ha funcionado donde colocan data[i]

Comment: Vázques obtuve lo que necesitaba y me di cuenta del error al acceder de una a data.producto muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda. Saludos amigo

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
 console.log(response.data[i].ProductoCategoria);
}

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de maravilla

Comment: Vázquez amigo perdona, ese for hiciste sera posible meter ese (var... etc) en un   $.each(data.data, function (i, item) ?